# External IDE-to-USB drive reads in bursts

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, pata

External IDE hard drive formatted FAT32. Connected via an IDE-to-USB adapter. OS: Windows XP

Tried two different adapters (different manufacturers), same results. Reads fine in bursts of ~500MB, then the entire machine (Explorer, apps, etc) all hang for about ~2mins. Copying then resumes again.

Same behavior whether copying lots of small files (1-2MB) or large files (> 1GB). Happened with three different drives so far, ranging in size from 6GB to 20GB.

Any ideas on what's going on here, or how to resolve it?

**This issue does not occur on NTFS formatted drives.**

Comment: There is another post here which might be related: http://superuser.com/questions/346660/write-caching-causes-slower-performance

Comment: Audio is enabled and no "ding" from USB disconnect/reconnect?

Comment: I was thinking power actually. External power for HD?

Comment: I didn't mean faulty cable, I meant power supplied externally from wall rather than over USB. Seems your answer is yes, external power. Right now because of hangs, it sounds mostly like bad blocks and retries, especially in light of the small size of the drives (=old). Possibly coincidence WRT NTFS, or perhaps NTFS has a faster fail mechanism.